# Continue script on the already opened browser instance in selenium with java

Tags: selenium, webdriver

My question is when ever i hit the restapi URL from my selenium it ask for authentication to return data in JSON format as for the same i provide username and password... but its not accepting the username and password and SHows message "required uname and password. The server says : protected area"
This is only happening in the browser which is getting opened through selenium
when i normally open the browser it accept the uname and password
i tried on the IE, Chrome and mozilla and the same problem persist
Is there any way that when i run my code it should not open the new browser window rather than use the new tab in already opened browser ......

Comment: what language are you using? You can add user info like cookie to the browser then the page should loaded with logged in.

Comment: In selenium every time it opens a new browser tab with no cookies and cache.

Comment: you can add user cookie after opening the browser then refresh it to see changing like `JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; ` then execute it  but you need to find cookie in your browser manually `executor.executeScript("document.cookie = 'user=cookie_info_get_from_browser; path=/;'"); `

Comment: But the question is why its not accepting the username and password in the new window which is getting opened by selenium and can it be possible that i can open the url in already opened browser in new tab... rather than new window.

Comment: show whatever you do it is not understandable.